# calling graph from asp .net core signalr hub

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to get groups from AzureAD by calling graph in the hub in the `OnConnectedAsync()` to add the current user to groups.

When calling my graph service from a controller it works just fine and returns me the data I want, but when calling it from inside the hub I get an error:

> IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.  No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

Any idea?

Here is my graph service :

```cs
public class GraphService : IGraphService
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public GraphService(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
                        IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = clientFactory;
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Group>> GetUserGroupsAsync()
    {
        var graphClient = await GetGraphClient();

        var memberShipCollection = await graphClient
            .Me
            .MemberOf
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        return memberShipCollection
            .OfType<Group>();
    }

    private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphClient()
    {
        var token = await _tokenAcquisition
            .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(client)
        {
            AuthenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            })
        };

        graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
        return graphClient;
    }
}
```

The hub :

```cs
[Authorize]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    ILogger<NotificationHub> _logger;
    private readonly IGraphService _graphService;

    public NotificationHub(ILogger<NotificationHub> logger, 
                           IGraphService graphService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _graphService = graphService;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();

        var userDynamicGroups = await GetUserDynamicGroupsAsync();

        //foreach (var group in userDynamicGroups)
        //    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group.DisplayName);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);

        //var userDynamicGroups = await GetUserDynamicGroupsAsync();

        //foreach (var group in userDynamicGroups)
        //    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group.DisplayName);
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Group>> GetUserDynamicGroupsAsync()
    {
        var AllUserGroups = await _graphService.GetUserGroupsAsync();
        return AllUserGroups.Where(g => g.DisplayName.Contains("ONE_"));
    }

}
```

The part related to auth in my startup:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddInternalAuthentification(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        Func<MessageReceivedContext, Task> existingOnMessageReceivedHandler = options.Events.OnMessageReceived;
        options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
        {
            await existingOnMessageReceivedHandler(context);

            StringValues accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            PathString path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/Notify"))
                context.Token = accessToken;
        };
    });
    return services;
}
```

Comment: when you connect to the hub in your signalr client do you provide `access_token` as a query parameter?

Comment: in the startup the access token is passed to the context which is available in the hub (context.Token = accessToken; )